# Fixing real-life offset of a simulated amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier

My simulation shown below has no offset voltage problem at all. In real life however, I am afraid that I would get a constant offset to the output instead of zero. Am I correct?

I tried to plug many resistors in here and I can't see where I can put a potentiometer so in case I would have an offset in real life, then I would be able to fix it.

Where can I connect a potentiometer (resistor in simulation) so I can tune the offset?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't know what specific type of offset you're thinking about, but you might consider using a chopper amplifier if you're concerned about input offset voltage. Or just a really low-offset amplifier, like a MAX4238 for instance.

Comment: Actually, on second look, it looks like the MAX4238 might be a chopper amplifier. The point still stands though.

Comment: LT1028 data dheet has suggested offset voltage correction. https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/1028fd.pdf

Comment: Page 14 of the [LT1028 data sheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/1028fd.pdf) shows how to apply offset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, you are want to add some circuit to "ideal" amplifier to model real amplifier offset? Or add some circuit to real amplifier to get rid of it offset?

Anyway, the "ideal" zero-offset amplifier means that the inputs must be at the same potential to have reasonable, limited output. The "offset" means that inputs must have some voltage difference - offset voltage to have limited output.
So, to model that voltage, one need to add ideal voltage source sequentially with one of input.

Answer (score 0):

A real op amp has a bias voltage between the inverting and non-inverting input that will get amplified just as if it were a signal (and more offsets that depend on bias currents)

In this case, your overall gain is 32^2 between your two stages, so the bias on the first stage will be multiplied by 1024.

My concern would be that the offset after the first stage might be enough to saturate the second stage output.  Therefore, I recommend routing the output of the first stage to a summing amp or some such to remove the offset on the output of stage 1 before passing the signal to stage 2.